# Nashorn memory leak Much memory is consumed by jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.JO4P0

Tags: nashorn

We are using Nashorn to use javascript from java (JDK 1.8 U66),after some profiling we are seeing a larger data is getting occupied by jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.JO4P0 
Object. Would like to know if any one have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.JO4PO and other similar instances are used to represent scripts objects from your scripts. But, you need to provide more info for further investigation. I suggest you please write to nashorn-dev openjdk alias with profiler output + more info. about your application (like to project, if open source, would be useful

Comment: This was fixed by using the variables as var jsInteger = Java.type("java.lang.Integer"); instead of var i = new Integer;